# Retrying a rule X times

Tags: python, snakemake

Is there a built-in or standard way to tell snakemake to retry a rule untill it successfully produces the output, or reaches a maximum number of retries? This is relevant for example when the rule communicates with some remote server, and the process may fail.
I thought of doing something like:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "file2.txt"

rule try:
    input:
        "file1.txt"
    output:
        "file2.txt"
    run:
        t = 1
        while t <= 3:
            try:
                shell("<API call> {input} > {output}")
                break
            except:
                print("Failed!")
                t += 1
                if t <= 3:
                    print("Retrying...")
                    shell("sleep 10")
                else:
                    print("Max number of retries reached.")
```

But is this the way to go?

Comment: You can use a for loop with `range` instead (something like `for t in range(3): ...`)

Answer (score 4):

This functionality exists in Snakemake now, via per rule `retries` directive, or globally via `--retries` command-line option:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=retries#defining-retries-for-fallible-rules

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it exists for specific rules, but snakemake has the `--restart-times` option. So you can do something like:

```
snakemake --cores 10 --restart-times 3
```

If you want it for specific rule(s) only then I would do something like this. I am not sure if snakemake gives an exception when a shell call fails. Probably you have to change the try except into something like:

```
for try in range(3):
    shell("mycommand")
    if (os.path.exists(output[0]) and os.path.getsize(output[0]) > 0):
        break
```

Or check if the file contains the stuff you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's a possible solution. Regarding your second point, I'm not sure this is really necessary, since Snakemake will exit with a "Missing output" error if the command failed and the output file was not created.

Comment: @soungalo I edited to make my point a bit more clear. I meant that if you want to have it only for specific rules then you probably have to use the check if the output exists.